# 405 (Method Not Allowed) Error from Vercel App to openshift backend application Post API Request

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, post, openshift, vercel

I deployed my React.js application on vercel and my spring boot backend application on openshift and made the necessary configurations, but I am getting 405(Method Not Allowed) error when sending a request to the backend.

```
BillingInput.js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', excelFile);
formData.append('productCode', productCode);
formData.append('customerType', customerType);

const response = await axios.post('https://sernteklifal.vercel.app/api/getProduct', formData, {
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
   },
});

ProductController.java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://sernteklifal.vercel.app")
public class ProductController {
    
    @PostMapping("/api/getProduct")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> getProduct(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, @RequestParam String productCode, @RequestParam String customerType) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Product product = findProductByProductCode(sheet, productCode, customerType);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(product);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}


vercel.json
{
  "rewrites": [
    { 
      "source": "/api",
      "destination": "https://billing-calculate-backend-hilaldlr-dev.apps.sandbox-m3.1530.p1.openshiftapps.com" }
  ]
}
```